# Shiny: error 71 [description=Package field not found in...]

Tags: shiny, shiny-server

I'm running a ShinyApp on our own RShiny-Server. I have a DESCRIPTION file in order to use the Showcase mode. Until now everything went smooth, but today I saw the following error in the log file.

Can anyone help on the following error in my Shiny log file?

> ERROR system error 71 (Protocol error) [description=Package field not found in /home/[…]/DESCRIPTION]
>   OCCURED AT: read@core/r-util/RPackageInfo.cpp#85
>   LOGGED FROM: isPackageDirectory@core/r_util/RPackageInfo.cpp#121

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Are you trying to load that package field somewhere? On Cran there is no such package. If you installed it from github, you might have to install it aswell on the RShiny-Server.

Comment: No I don't load a package `field`. 

However since our Shiny Server has been updated, the error has disappeared.